# Flutter - Como passar lista de IDs do Firestore para um FutureBuilder?

Tags: dart, flutter, firestore

Estou desenvolvendo um app de livros e preciso de auxílio em carregar a lista de livros favoritos do usuário.

Não sei o a forma que estou fazendo seria a mais correta, estou salvando os IDs de todos os livros que o usuário favorita numa lista no firestore, depois recupero essa lista dentro da lista **favoritesId** dentro do método **getFavoritesId()**, e agora é onde ocorre o problema, dentro do método **_makeFavoriteList()**, como recuperar os somente os dados dos livros que possuem os ids  dentro desta lista e mostrá-los no GridView?

[image: coleção livros]

[image: coleção usuários]

```
class FavoriteScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _FavoriteScreenState createState() => _FavoriteScreenState();
}

class _FavoriteScreenState extends State<FavoriteScreen> {

  CollectionReference booksRef = Firestore.instance.collection("books");
  Future<QuerySnapshot> futureBooks;
  UserModel model = UserModel();
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  List<String> favoritesId = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    getFavoritesId();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getFavoritesId() async{

    List<String> favoritesId = [];

  firebaseUser = await _auth.currentUser();

  DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("users")
      .document(firebaseUser.uid).get();

  if(querySnapshot.exists && querySnapshot.data.containsKey("favorites") &&
    querySnapshot.data["favorites"] is List && querySnapshot.data["favorites"].length != null){

    for(int i= 0; i < querySnapshot.data["favorites"].length; i++){
      favoritesId.add(querySnapshot.data["favorites"][i]);

    }
    print(favoritesId);

  }

  }

  Future<dynamic> _makeFavoriteList() async{

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    for(int i =0; i < favoritesId.length; i++){

     futureBooks = booksRef.where("id", isEqualTo: favoritesId[i]).getDocuments();

    }

    print(futureBooks);

    return futureBooks;

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    timeDilation = 2.5;

    Widget _buildFavoriteGridItem(context, index){

      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Material(
            elevation: 7.0,
            shadowColor: Colors.blueAccent.shade700,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DetailScreen()
                ));
              },
              child: Hero(
                tag: index['title'],
                child: Image.network(
                  index["cover"],
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  height: 132,
                  width: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 5),
            child: Text(index["title"],
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 2,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,

              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Favoritos"),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        /*actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () async {

                showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch());

              }
          )
        ],*/
      ),

      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _makeFavoriteList,
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return GridView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 16),
                  primary: false,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                        (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                    //crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                    //mainAxisSpacing: 3
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return _buildFavoriteGridItem(context, snapshot[index]);
                  },
                );

              } else {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                );
              }
            },

          ),

        ],
      )


    );

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que uma forma de fazer seria:

Para isso você deveria mudar a declaração do *futureBook* para uma lista vazia. `List()`

```
Future<dynamic> _makeFavoriteList() async{

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    for(int i =0; i < favoritesId.length; i++){

        List<DocumentSnapshot> futureBooks = List();

        futureBooks.add(await booksRef.document(id).get());

    }

    print(futureBooks.toList().toString());

    return futureBooks;

}
```

O loop irá repetir adicionando à lista somente os livros favoritos. Não consigo testar isso então comente qualquer coisa, ao que tudo indica deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma complicação que existe ao usar o firestore é realizar os JOINS da vida...
A maneira que você fez é uma saída para o problema, só é necessário você realizar algumas pequenas modificações.

Como você já possuí os IDs de todos os livros favoritos, não é necessário realizar um `where` para trazer os *documents* com os dados dos livros, basta você acessá-los diretamente por seu ID.

```
Future<dynamic> _makeFavoriteList() async{
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

  List<DocumentSnapshot> books = [];

  for(int i =0; i < favoritesId.length; i++){
    book = await booksRef.document(favoritesId[i]).get();
    books.add(book);
  }

  return books;
}
```